# Blender model not importing to Roblox Studio

Tags: export, bezier-curves, nurbs-surface

I've just gotten into Blender because I want to make assets for a game of my own in Roblox however I've ran into a problem where my model doesn't appear when I export it as FBX into Roblox Studio.

An error message pops up when I try exporting the model saying the file dimensions are too big but this only happens when the strings of the guitar are also in the model. I've tried exporting the model without the strings and it works fine. I'm using the NurbsPath Curve for the strings if that helps.

Is there a work around/solution for this? Sorry if this is the wrong place since the error is related more to Roblox Studio than Blender but Im unable to access DevForum.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess you are right that this might be a Roblox problem, but if I read your question correctly, the error message saying the file dimensions are too big appears upon export - so this means exporting from Blender, which makes it a Blender error message, not Roblox? Could you upload your file on https://blend-exchange.com and follow the instructions there to edit it into your question? This could help to investigate what causes the export error.